# Hosting nettcp WCF service in IIS7 fails

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

Ok, so I have a really simple WCF service that I would like to host under IIS. I have enabled the "Windows Communication Foundation Non-Http Activation" so that is not the problem. I am running IIS 7,5 on a Windows 7 computer with .NET 4.0 installed. My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FirstWcfService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="NetTcpServiceTest.IMySuperService"
            bindingConfiguration="tcpbinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mextcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false
              and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
               set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid
               disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpbinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <!--<security mode="None"></security>-->
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="mexTcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The service is hosted as an application called "NetTcpServiceTest" under the default web site in IIS. When I try to add a reference to net.tcp://localhost/NetTcpServiceTest/MySuperService.svc/mextcp in visual studio I get the following error:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/NetTcpServiceTest/MySuperService.svc/mextcp'.
The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/NetTcpServiceTest/MySuperService.svc/mextcp' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

And the error in the event log is:

```
An error occurred while trying to listen for the URL '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/NetTcpServiceTest'. This worker process will be terminated.
 Sender Information: net.tcp
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.TcpAppDomainProtocolHandler/65824025
 Process Name: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: .
```

I have also enabled the binding for the site and application. Does anyone know how to solve this? When I search for it on internet the only answer I found was to re-install IIS and .NET, but that doesn't sounds like a real solution for me.

Comment: the thing is that when I got a new computer the problem went away, I can host nettcp services under IIS on my new Win7. So I didn't find the answer to my problem. Do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you have installed IIS after .NET, try `aspnet_regiis.exe`.